# What are the generators and relations of $SO(2, \mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$SO(2, \mathbb{Q})$ is a group of special orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrices with rational coefficients. It is a countably infinite subgroup of the 2d rotation group $SO(2, \mathbb{R}) \sim U(1)$.

Elements of $SO(2, \mathbb{Q})$ naturally correspond to Pythagorean triples: a triple $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ gives rise to the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a}{c} & \frac{b}{c} \\
 -\frac{b}{c} & \frac{a}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Which basic properties of the group $SO(2, \mathbb{Q})$ are known? For example, is it generated by a finite number of generators? Are the generators known?

Comment: No, it is not finitely generated --- consider the denominators and the fact every $p\equiv 1\pmod4$ is a sum of two squares and thus the hypotenuse of a primitive Pythagorean triple.

Comment: @DietrichBurde isn’t that group simply a cyclic group of order 4?